# Why is the text visible, but the background is not?

Tags: css

I have following mark up:

```
<div class="one">Content</div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

and following style sheets:

```
.one, .two {
    height: 20px;
}
.one {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.two {
    background-color: #0f0;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Why is the text `Content` visible, but the red background is not? I would expect the text also to be only partly visible due to the given style sheets.

For your convenience, I also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5LfZ/).

Comment: Looks fine to me (Chrome)

Comment: The red background is also visible to me (using latest Chrome).

Comment: Can you explain what you expect as output?

Comment: in Chrome and IE8 red background **is **visible, but only 10px of it, because of your negative margin on div two.

Comment: I am sorry for any misunderstandings. the red div is also visible to me, but only 10 pixel. yet the text is fully visible even though it is inside the red div

Comment: I think we solved it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052402/strange-css-behavior-with-layers/15053892#answer-15053892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that text of first div would be only partly visible, you need to use position and z-index.

```
.one, .two {
    height: 20px;
}
.one {
    background-color: #f00;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.two {
    background-color: #0f0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v5LfZ/2/

Comment: This solves the problem but it does not explain why my versions.behaves like it behaves?!?

Comment: Because background is background and he deserves to be in background, but if you want that your background would not be in background - use z-index :)