# Strange css behavior with layers

Tags: html, css, image, background

Recently i worked at site gallery, and trying to make description label in front of image. So, this is how it should look:

[image]

its html:

```
<li class="project-item">
  <img src="images/project_example.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="annotation">
    <div class="annotation_head">Head</div>
    <div class="annotation_footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Block with .annotation class is absolute, and .project-item is relative. 
But before that i used another solution which look odd to me, and i cant explain its behavior. Here it is:

[image]

I replaced `position: absolute` rule with `margin-top: -50px`, and change `color` from black to red, for clarity.
Strange thing is, that background color displayed back from image, but it should be in front of it, why ? is there any reasonably css rule ?

Comment: Show us your **CSS**. Or make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @Vucko updated with links

Comment: Remove `position:static;` from `.slider .project-item .annotation`. That should bring the whole `.annotation` to front. Or you want some other efect ?

Comment: Nope, i`ve set to static, because want override absolute value. Everything works like i want on the first link, i cant understand why image layer displayed over background annotation

Comment: ok, this is weird... Why the background of `.annotation` is behind the img and the text is in front?

Comment: That's the first time I see something like that, apparently that's the way `static` elements are rendered,seems odd and wrong to me but I've done some tests and I had the same results, an elements content gets in front of another elements background http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/U445r/ we learn something new every day! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing text separated from it's background is because element backgrounds and foregrounds are independent.

I added a black background to the `.project-item` `li` and you can see that the red child bg is correctly positioned on top of the black parent bg.  `.annotation` appears in the DOM after the `img` so those foregrounds are also properly layered.  If you want your red annotation background to be visible above the `li` foreground then you are required to start a new document flow scoped within `li.project-item`.

In this case the desired positioning is achieved with `.slider .project-item .annotation{ position: absolute;}` which is currently overridden by your `static` positioning.

[image: Backgrounds layered properly]

Comment: is it documented somewhere, that background is separated ? there must be some rule on which browsers look at

Comment: W3C specs define it pretty clearly in 14.1 and 14.2.  `color` means foreground.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html "Backgrounds of elements that form a stacking context are painted at the bottom of the element's stacking context, below anything in that stacking context."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think description in link that you gave, is reffered properly to z-index, anyway i will search for deep explanations in w3.org.